# How to get string with special characters from command line output by using BufferedReader

Tags: java, utf-8, bufferedreader

I have a class to get output from command line:

```
public final class StreamPumper implements Runnable {
  // input param is process.getInputStream()
  private BufferedReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(input, encoding)));
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      String str = reader.readLine();
      while (str != null) {
        consumeLine(str);
        str = reader.readLine();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
    }
  }
}
```

reader.readLine() will return `[32m  √ [39m [90mResponse status: 200 -  Login[39m`, but I expect is  `√  Has 'error' in response body - error: unauthorized`

Another ex: `[90m│[39m                         [90m│[39m executed [90m│[39m   failed [90m│[39m`

, I expect is `│                         │ executed │   failed │`

How can I get string with special characters from command line output by using this class?
It work well on command line screen (Eclispe, IntelliJ, shell), but the issue occurs when using debugging or saving to file.
[image]

Comment: Where do you see that output? These look like terminal escape codes and not something you got from input.

Comment: Sorry, I updated desc, input is process.getInputStream()

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the encoding corresponding to the special characters you are expecting.

The following will work fine for special characters included in `UTF-8`

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in,"UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String str = br.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
```

Since you are using LineNumberReader which extends BufferedReader the following code works fine for the special symbol mentioned above:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in,"UTF-8");
        LineNumberReader br = new LineNumberReader(isr);
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String str = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
```

[image]

Find the image below:

Comment: Thanks for quickly reply. I use this.reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"))); but it still does not get special character. Thanks.

Comment: Which special character are you trying to read? Does UTF-8 include it?

Comment: Oh, It show right in command line, but when I get string by line and save to file the issue will appear

Comment: @TamVo So while writing you must specify the encoding as well :)

Comment: I inserted the image to my desc :)

Comment: You are not reading UTF-8 data, i am not sure but you can try with latin encoding `ISO-8859-1`